# In Nextjs, how to programatically trigger server side rendering?

Tags: next.js

We know that Router.push() triggers client-side rendering. 
But how can I programatically trigger server-side rendering to a page?

Example: I have a login modal which on submit sends a api call to check user data. Once I got the info that the user is ok, I want to load a page but via a server-side rendering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to server-side render a page, you can't navigate to it using `Router` or `Link` - you should use native `a` or `window.location` functionality. In your case, after you get the response from the API, you want to trigger a redirect (as if the user clicked a link), so you should call:

```js
window.location.href = "https://{yourDestination}"
```

This will force a request to the server. As you've experienced, `Router` and `Link` attempt to keep everything on the client side.

Comment: Many thanks. I knew it had to be that simple :) But I was thinking Nextjs has some special way to do that. Now I understand that this is not necessary since we can use window.location.